# Passing Form-data Array from one function to another function in same controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, function

I have a multidimensional array containing data from a form and I need this array in another Controller in the same controller to continue working with it, but I don't know how I do that.

The array can look like this example:

```
array [
    "absender" => "Maxim Ivan",
    "email" => "maximivan@example.com",
    "telefon" => "1234567890",
    "fax" => null,
    "grund" => "Gehaltserhöhung",
    "termin" => [
        0 => [
            "person" => "Some Name",
            "meeting" => "10.05"  
        ],
        1 => [
            "person" => "Another Name",
            "meeting" => "18.05"  
        ],
        2 => [
            "person" => "Again another name",
            "next-possible-meeting" => "1"  
        ],
        3 => [
            "person" => "And again",
            "next-possible-meeting" => "1"  
        ],
    ],
    "bemerkung" => "some notes by Maxim"
]
```

This array is created(and the input data validated) in the `store`-method of the 'TerminController'.
This method will return a view where all of this data gets displayed again, to let the user check the info and can then add a document.

When the document is added and the data gets submitted with an input-button the `upload`-method in the same Controller gets called.

And there's where I need the array with the form-data to go on working with it.

But how do I achieve passing the array through to the next function that is only called with an input-button.

First approach was to save the array into the session, which did even work even though it was hard due to the multidimensional; but it's a really ugly solution.

**Should I save the input data into a database in the `store`-method and fetch it again in the `upload`-method?**

Or is it somehow possible to pass the array through the Controllers/ make it accessible in the `upload`-Controller even though it gets created in another one?

I have also heard something about using `serialize()`and `unserialize()`, but I'm not exactly sure how this could help me..

Or maybe there's another and even better solution I just don't think of? 
I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

The array varies, it can be 17 arrays nested in 'termin' but I can also be just one.

Comment: I still think session is the way to go. The data you're dealing with doesn't have to be persisted for long. Otherwise, save it in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in the [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#cache-usage):

```
Cache::put('multiArray', $multiArray); //put array in cache
$array = Cache::get('multiArray'); //retreive from cache
```

Comment: isn't this kind of similiar to storing it in the session?

Comment: there is another way to do this

Comment: 1. json_encode this multidimensional array. 2. Pass this json to view. 3. Pass this json with input type `hidden` to your `upload` method. 4. json_decode the json to get back your array

Comment: Do I have to json_encode it to do that? Isn't it possible to just pass the array as it is with input type hidden?

Comment: you can re-create this array with input type hidden in your blade using @foreach

Comment: I know that and I already do, I was asking if I could pass the array with the input type hidden without `json_encode` it first, but i just found out I can't